# stage.toJSON() load in html5 and kineticJS

Tags: jquery, html, kineticjs

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container2');

    var ball = new Image();
    var cone = new Image();
    var tshirt = new Image();
    ball.onload = function() {
        stage.get('.ball').apply('setImage', ball);
        stage.get('.cone').apply('setImage', cone);
        stage.get('.tshirt').apply('setImage', tshirt);
        stage.draw();
    };
    ball.src = 'images/sport_soccer.png';
    cone.src = 'images/cone.png';
    tshirt.src = 'images/school_events.png';
});
```

Show button load the stage in a new div i load it fine but if i have three images on the stage it load it three times in the new stage and so on

also when i use

```
ball.onload = function() {
    stage.get('.ball').apply('setImage', ball);
    stage.draw();
};

tshirt.onload = function() {
    stage.get('.tshirt').apply('setImage', tshirt);
    stage.draw();
};

cone.onload = function() {
    stage.get('.cone').apply('setImage', cone);
    stage.draw();
};
```

the same problem here.

Comment: can you post the json data as well?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create items on click in a show event. Create your kinetic objects on page load then have show button make the stage etc visible. This avoid duplication on many clicks.

Comment: I'can't make it on page load because the json variable is empty in first i have a save button that save the stage in json variable.then when i click 'show' show the stage.